# Does PHP have any hardware or system requirements?

Tags: php, server, updates, requirements

I've been told by the sysadmin that its impossible to update the php version on the webservers in my workplace because they are "old".

**Is this true?**

**Does PHP has any hardware or system requirements?**

Thanks

Comment: I am pretty sure you can find this information by using Google.

Comment: Just out of curiousity, how "old"?  Like what OS and version are we talking here if you can share?

Comment: Google brought me here... I've found that 1st gen Intel i7 / Xeon CPUs don't have the feature set needed for PHP 7 speed improvements. Running PHP7 on that generation hardware is actually slower than the latest PHP5. It still runs, but switching from 4 cores of a Xeon X5650 to 4 cores of a Xeon Silver 4110 shaved 70% of the time to first byte for our web server. When the single thread rating is only 28% faster, see https://www.cpubenchmark.net/compare/Intel-Xeon-X5650-vs-Intel-Xeon-Silver-4110/1304vs3106

Answer (score 2):

PHP does have official support for Windows versions, they are detailed [here](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.legacy.index.php).

On Unix machines, any sysadmin can install PHP7 with enough determination on most machines. My guess is that your sysadmin prefers to stick with the PHP that their preferred package manager provides. For instance, Debian 7 only has PHP 5.4 with default apt-get repositories.

Answer (score 2):

PHP doesn't have any hardware limitations I've ever encountered, but one thing that will certainly stop you from compiling newer versions of PHP on older *nix systems is software.

Modern versions of PHP won't compile on older *nix systems because they don't have the required tools to build PHP (a modern C compiler, semi-recent versions of glibc, GNU make, Bison, and a lot of the PHP extensions will have prerequisites of newer library versions that are incompatible with the ones installed on older systems).

That might very well be why they're saying that.  I've tried to compile PHP 5.4 on RedHat 7.3 without much luck because all those system libraries and tools for compiling software are too old.  With the OpenSSL extension, old systems often don't even have the right header files with function prototypes PHP is expecting during compilation.

So yes, compiling PHP is difficult or impossible on an older system (ever tried building newer versions of libc on old machines??? It's a nightmare!).

For example, I took PHP 5.6.22 and started to compile on Red Hat Linux release 7.3 (Valhalla) and didn't get very far...

First simple error:

```
checking for zlib version >= 1.2.0.4... 1.1.4
configure: error: libz version greater or equal to 1.2.0.4 required
```

That's easy enough to compile by itself, but a number of other libraries for extensions I wanted aren't installed on the system, and trying to compile each one might be a rabbit hole of its own.

So I took out the ones that we didn't have to begin with, was able to `./configure` just fine, but not too far into `make`...

```
php-5.6.22/ext/openssl/openssl.c: In function `php_openssl_get_stream_from_ssl_handle':
php-5.6.22/ext/openssl/openssl.c:581: warning: passing arg 1 of `SSL_get_ex_data' discards qualifiers from pointer target type
php-5.6.22/ext/openssl/openssl.c: In function `php_openssl_get_evp_cipher_from_algo':
php-5.6.22/ext/openssl/openssl.c:1092: warning: return makes pointer from integer without a cast
php-5.6.22/ext/openssl/openssl.c:1095: warning: return makes pointer from integer without a cast
php-5.6.22/ext/openssl/openssl.c:1098: warning: return makes pointer from integer without a cast
php-5.6.22/ext/openssl/openssl.c: In function `openssl_x509v3_subjectAltName':
php-5.6.22/ext/openssl/openssl.c:1874: `GENERAL_NAMES' undeclared (first use in this function)
...
php-5.6.22/ext/openssl/openssl.c: In function `zif_openssl_digest':
php-5.6.22/ext/openssl/openssl.c:5112: void value not ignored as it ought to be
make: *** [ext/openssl/openssl.lo] Error 1
```

So with OpenSSL it was game over (it's version 0.9.6b by the way, so old!).  I could probably compile newer OpenSSL as I've done before without trouble, but this 7.3 system is also special.  We've put a lot of effort into bringing newer versions of unsupported software (libs & compiler) to this system to keep it alive, but on older ones I've had far less luck.

So yeah it might take days to get newer PHP going on older systems and this assumes lots of experience and knowledge on how to build and install libraries outside of your library path (so they don't interfere with other things on the system) and then get the new stuff to dynamically link to those).

Comment: Thank you for your response, i understand that it might be impossible or very hard and tedious to install recent versions of this software due to dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

**These are the minimum system requirements to download and install WampServer:**
Operating System: Windows XP (32 or 64 bits)
HDD: 200 MB free space.
Memory: 512 MB RAM.
Full administrator Access.

**These are for first install after this in production environment**

*You won't be limited.*
PROC : 0 until you show the menu, all work is done by the two services
RAM : only services, so it depends of how many connection apache must manage (1 in a local use)
HDD : It depends of how many addons/apps you install and of your projects size and databases.